# django equivalent to sqlalchemy's sessionmaker

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I'm new to Django 1.9 (fairly new to flask, as well), and am trying to populate my models.py much in the same way that sqlite sessionmaker does it.

this is a snip of my models.py:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Location(models.Model):
def __str__(self):
    return self.location_text

location_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
travel_date = models.DateTimeField('date traveled')


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Countries(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.capitals

    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    capitals = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

With flask and sqlalchemy I'd create a new file and be able to do something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from this_app.models import Location, Countries

engine = create_engine("the db")
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

loc1 = Location(location_text = "Indonesia")
session.add(loc1)
session.commit()

cap = Countries(
    capitals="Jakarta",
    location=loc1
    )
session.add(cap)
session.commit()
```

How is this done with django's orm?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The same tutorial that showed you how to create your models would have shown you how to add data to them.

Comment: Hey Daniel, If it did, I didnt see it. The only thing I saw on the django tutorial site was how to add info using the shell. I have an inventory list of too many to do on the shell, and would like the option of doing it similar to what flask allows.

Comment: Why would using the shell be any different from any other code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get you right, you want to save objects in one query.

This could be done with [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are)

Answer (score 0):

```
loc1 = Location.objects.create(location_text="Indonesia")
cap = Countries.objects.create(capitals="Jakarta", location=loc1)
```

That's all.